# Getting Error in reading website content using c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get Web Page Contents in Code with C# but its giving me error. Please help me to fix it.

```
  string url = "http://www.abesoft.org/query.asp
                searchtype=ANY&
                query_param=USDOT&original_query_param=NAME&
                query_string=2134430&original_query_string=NATIONAL GRASS LLC";

 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
 WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
 Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
 string html = String.Empty;
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
 {
      html = sr.ReadToEnd();
 }
```

Error- `"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."`

Comment: I think the problem is that website needs/wants a secure connection...

Comment: Are you sure this is the right error for this code? You are using `http`, not `https`?

Comment: error is same if i used https

Comment: I can see why the https error, try going to https://www.safersys.org in Chrome or Firefox and you'll see the certificate problem. Not sure why you'd get that error on non-https.

Comment: It probably has a 301/302 to HTTPS, by default, the GetResponse will follow redirects

Comment: yes even i am able to open this without https..

Comment: I must add this question. Pankaj do you have permission to connect to this website for official business?  If you do not have permission to connect to this website in this manner then we cannot help you.  It would literally be a crime to help you achieve something that might be against the law.

Comment: The code above works for me (using HTTP) and fixing the url (i.e. removing the white space and adding the ? for the querystring). HTTPS does not work (I get the error you specified). Do you need to use HTTPS or something? Not sure what the problem is here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use:

```
 ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = delegate { return true; };
```

To ignore the certificate errors.  Source is this article:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/Feb/11/HttpWebRequest-and-Ignoring-SSL-Certificate-Errors

Basically you are just trying to ignore the bad certificate on that site.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 string url =@"http://www.safersys.org/query.asp?
                searchtype=ANY&query_type=queryCarrierSnapshot&
                query_param=USDOT&original_query_param=NAME&
                query_string=2134430&original_query_string=NATIONAL GRASS LLC";

 HttpWebRequest request =  (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
 request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

 WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
 Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
 string html = String.Empty;
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
 {
      html = sr.ReadToEnd();
 }
```